Find the highest triplet
I'm trying to create a function that receives a input list and return the sum of the highest triplet. My code is meant to take the highest 3 unique values (NO duplicates) and add them together and return the highest possible sum of the values.
Not sure why but the following function doesn't work when I run the tests on HackerRank.
Constraints:
1 ≤ n ≤4000
1 ≤ profit[I] ≤ 10^9
# Input samples:
# profit = [2, 10, 33, 2, 5]  # here, the result should be 5+10+33 = 48
# profit = [2, 1, 33, -6, 5, 10, 10]  # here, the result should be 5+10+33 = 48 (ignore duplicate 10)

def getMaximumProfit(profit):
    # Debug the below code to return the required output.
    maxi = 0
    for i in range(len(profit)-2):
        total = sum(profit[i:i+3])
        if maxi > total:
            maxi += total
        total = 0
    return total


"Not sure why but the following function doesn't work when I run the tests on HackerRank." - what happened when you ran it locally?

it runs fine, however when click run tests.. it doesn't pass all the tests.. so there are some input cases which it doesn't work for

Why are you only checking consecutive triplets? Sort your list first and then take the last triplet...

The expected result that you posted consist on adding 3 numbers that are not consecutive. If triplets don't have to be consecutive, then the problem is just finding the top 3 biggest numbers.

What does "highest triplet" mean?

The three highest values in example 2 are 33, 10, 10. If you want to exclude duplicates, you need to state it clearly...

Can you copy the problem description from HackerRank? I found Maximizing the Profit but it's different from this.

What's the HackerRank URL of this problem?

What's the n from the constraints? You don't talk about it and it doesn't appear in your code, either.

You can take advantage of the sorted(list) method.
By sorting the list in reverse and getting the first 3 values, we can add up these values to get the highest possible number derived from 3 values in the input list. We also have to consider that duplicates should not be counted in the sum (using set(list) method to remove duplicate values).
def getMaximumProfit(profit):
    # Get all 3 highest integers
    returnVal: int = 0
    highest = sorted(set(profit), reverse=True)[:3]
    for value in highest:
        returnVal += value # Add all integers
    return returnVal


or as a 1-liner: return sum(sorted(profit)[-3:])

@Julien Fails the second example.

Second example is an obvious copy paste typo IMO, unless OP explains clearly expected behaviour...

I was thinking that too, I was confused when my code returned 53 instead of 48, then I looked at the list.

thanks @BrodyPadgett , it almost worked for all cases!!!
tit didn't work for one case which has a dup [ 2, 1, 5, 10, 10]

@Julien The right thing to do then is to ask them, not to pretend it's a typo and ignore it.

If you read the comments you see many people have already asked...

I don't have enough reputation to comment at the moment.

@Julien I don't see any asking about that other than your new one now, and in a broader sense mine. Both posted after this answer and your first comment.

@Peter What does "didn't work" mean? And why do you accept an answer that doesn't work?

Hi @nocomment, I'm just came here for help and to learn but people started voting negative on the question.. so I don't want cause problems, so I will try solve the the issue on my own

@Peter I you "don't want cause problems", then not fixing your question is exactly the wrong thing to do...

@PeterSmith I fixed the problem and now it doesn't include duplicates in the final addition.

To exclude duplicates too, you can use set:
sum(sorted(set(profit))[-3:])


This answer and axerotol's are good, but not optimal: sorting takes O(n log n), but here we only need the top three values, which can be done in 3*n comparison, i.e., O(n). That code would be less elegant, but I bet HackerRank will score a linear answer higher.

@joanis Using heapq.nlargest would be similarly elegant and O(n), but I think it would have a slower worst case than this answer.

I had a simpler idea in mind, based on using max() three times, with some care to avoid duplicates. Using a heap is a good idea, but you have to worry about duplicates, and maybe that's where the worse case for the heap solution hurts. My idea is simply: first = max(profit), second = max(p for p in profit if p<first) and third = max(p for p in profit if p < second) with try/except around the second and third init to catch the cases where there are three distinct values. This solution has best case = worse case = linear, with 5n comparisons, actually.

Although sum(heapq.nlargest(3, set(profit))) solves it, in linear time, handling the duplicates correctly. It makes copies of the data, unlike my max-based solution, but the worse case runtime is indeed linear.

@nocomment I just looked at the source code for heapq.nlargest(), and wow, that's well coded! This solution will be hard to beat, even in the worse case.

@joanis nlargest is good with random input, but bad and easy to beat with ascending input. It took around 0.2 ms with that, while Julien's took around 0.15 ms with random input.

@nocomment Oh, interesting. I stand corrected. I guess it's still linear, but ascending input causes the heap used to get updated for every item. Now I'd be curious to compare to my simpler max-based solution...

@joanis Yes, always maximal heap usage instead of (for random order) rarely any heap usage ever. Had a scale bug, was more like 2 ms vs 1.5 ms. Did better testing now.

@Julien Would you mind if I added a benchmark with solutions to your answer? (Or shall the three of us reopen the now improved question?)

@nocomment you don't need my permission for that, but sure :)

@nocomment I agree we should reopen, the question is clear now. I'll post my approach and it will be nice to have it included in your benchmarks asking with the others.

My solution for this problem is to go for a linear-time algorithm that requires no additional data structures. Given we only need the top three elements, we don't need to sort the whole list, and we don't need to remove all the duplicates.
This code will do the trick:
highest = max(profit)
second = max(p for p in profit if p < highest)
third = max(p for p in profit if p < second)
return highest + second + third

The key is that you don't need to actually remove duplicates, you only need to ignore duplicates of highest and second, which my generating expressions in the second and third calls to max() accomplish, filtering values we want to ignore before passing the rest to max().
However, this will raise a ValueError if there aren't three distinct values in profit, which I need to catch.
This, then, is my complete solution:
def getMaximumProfit(profit):
    highest, second, third = 0, 0, 0
    try:
        highest = max(profit)
        second = max(p for p in profit if p < highest)
        third = max(p for p in profit if p < second)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return highest + second + third

Run-time analysis: O(n), because this will do 5*n comparisons every time. It's probably faster than the the worst case with heapq.nlargest, but not faster than its best cases. Unknowns: I don't know how fast set creation is, which this solution does not require, but generating expressions (which I use to find second and third) have their own overhead, which might remove the advantage.
Space analysis: O(1), because this solution creates no temporary copies of the data.
PS: wait, values are non-negative!
I just noticed that the question specifies 1 ≤ profit[I] ≤ 10^9, which means we don't need to worry about 0 or negative values.
Taking that into account allows me to simplify my solution to this:
def getMaximumProfit1(profit):
    highest = max(profit, default=0)
    second = max((p for p in profit if p < highest), default=0)
    third = max((p for p in profit if p < second), default=0)
    return highest + second + third


What's the relevance of values being non-negative for using default=0?

The answer would be wrong for something like [-1, -1, -1], because second would be 0 and thus third would end up -1 again.

Two more solutions and a benchmark:
profit = random.choices(range(1, 10**9+1), k=4000)
  80 ± 0 μs  raw
 178 ± 2 μs  nlargest_set
 314 ± 2 μs  three_max
 345 ± 3 μs  groupby_sorted
 498 ± 2 μs  sorted_set

profit = list(range(1, 4001))
  26 ± 0 μs  groupby_sorted
  85 ± 2 μs  sorted_set
 101 ± 0 μs  raw
 312 ± 2 μs  three_max
 520 ± 5 μs  nlargest_set

Python: 3.11.9 (main, Apr  2 2024, 08:25:04) [GCC 13.3.0]

I think the first case is a worst case for sorted_set (due to sorting random order) and the second case is a worst case for nlargest_set (due to always having to maximally update its heap).
Code:
# mine
def groupby_sorted(profit):
    desc = sorted(profit, reverse=True)
    return sum(p for p, _ in islice(groupby(desc), 3))

# mine
def raw(profit):
    x = y = z = 0    # z = largest, y = second largest, x = third largest
    for p in profit:
        if p > y:
            if p > z:
                x = y
                y = z
                z = p
            elif p != z:
                x = y
                y = p
        elif p > x and p != y:
            x = p
    return x + y + z

# Julien's
def sorted_set(profit):
    return sum(sorted(set(profit))[-3:])

# Julien's but with nlargest
def nlargest_set(profit):
    return sum(nlargest(3, set(profit)))

# joanis's
def three_max(profit):
    highest = max(profit, default=0)
    second = max((p for p in profit if p < highest), default=0)
    third = max((p for p in profit if p < second), default=0)
    return highest + second + third

funcs = [sorted_set, nlargest_set, raw, three_max, groupby_sorted]

from heapq import nlargest
from itertools import groupby, islice
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from itertools import product
import sys
import random

# Correctness
def check():
    expect = funcs[0](profit)
    for f in funcs[1:]:
        result = f(profit)
        if result != expect:
            print(profit, expect, result, f.__name__)
            error

for n in range(1, 7):
    for profit in product(range(7), repeat=n):
        check()

cases = [
    'profit = random.choices(range(1, 10**9+1), k=4000)',
    'profit = list(range(1, 4001))',
]
for case in cases:
    exec(case)
    check()

# Speed
times = {case: {f: [] for f in funcs} for case in cases}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[case][f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):4.0f} ± {stdev(ts):1.0f} μs '
for _ in range(100):
    for case in cases:
        exec(case)
        random.shuffle(funcs)
        for f in funcs:
            t = timeit(lambda: f(profit), number=10) / 10
            times[case][f].append(t)
for case in cases:
    print(case)
    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)
    print()

print('Python:', sys.version)


Nice benchmarking, thank you! These are not the answer I expected.

@joanis I think it's the first time I did it like this, comparing worst case times when the solutions have different worst cases.

@joanis What did you expect instead? Or what surprised you most?

n<=4000 is significant here, because log(4000) is only 12, so n log n with this constraint is just 12 n. In general log(n) is remarkably small unless datasets are extremely large, I guess that's a lesson to remember from this. I ran your test with 40000 data points, and the ordering remains almost identical, it seems it would take a lot more before sorting really loses out.

My biggest surprise is how well sorting does, and that's something I'll keep in mind for the future.

And three_max is not doing as well as I hoped, but with its fixed 5n comparisons and its two generator expressions, it's not really that surprising.

Finally the full reversal of positions between near top and bottom for nlargest_set and sorted_set in random vs worse is enlightening, and illustrates well how optimal algorithm choices depend on the input in more than just the obvious ways.

@joanis Yeah I use 4000 elements because I think that's the limit in the question. And yes, sorting is pretty fast, especially sorting numbers. That then doesn't even use the int object comparison methods but a more direct C function.

@joanis Right, that reversal of positions is amusing. These worst cases for those two solutions are pretty much each other's best cases. With random order, nlargest rarely has to touch its heap, and with ascending order, sorted doesn't have to sort.

@joanis One more maybe interesting thing: Those two solutions first use set(profit), and sets are hash tables and not intentionally order-preserving. One might think that messes with the random order of the first case or the ascending order of the second case. But the values of the first case are sparse enough that the hashing pretty much just shuffles randomly, keeping it random. And the values in the second case are dense enough that the set doesn't change the order (in fact, if we shuffled the range(1, 4001), the set would sort it).
